# If statement from string statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I would like to ask if it's possible to write an *if*-statement using a string and convert it somehow into a real statement?

I wish I could use `"c==c"` like `if(c==c)`.
Is that possible?

```js
var c=1;
var aa= "c==c";
if(aa) {
    console.log("abc")
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a use case for [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). However, be sure to read up on the security implications of using `eval()` (e.g., [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more of your underlying problem.  `eval` is widely disparaged, for some good reasons.  But it or its kin (Function constructor) are the only ways to do this.  Perhaps there's some better way to deal with your underlying problem.

Comment: The structure of your string if statement will be allwasy like this "c==c"? or also other forms like this "c!=c"?

Comment: As stated, `eval()` can do this for you, but in almost every case, when we get to the root of the real problem, we can find an alternate solution because `eval === evil`. *I wish I could use "c==c" like if(c==c)* - Why do you wish this?

Comment: It was a simple example. I want to do sth like that to enter an JSON object like `"people[i].a". But I'm not sure if it's possible to do it with `eval()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use Javascript's eval function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Eval let's you run any string as valid Javascript code. However eval has a few downsides like performance and security since this can lead to vulnerabilities in your code if you let users eval any string they want.

Comment: canI use it also for objects?

Comment: for example `eval("people[i].a)"`

Comment: It's not hard to test that yourself, is it?